# Display url in text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOtherApps" Height="400" Width="400" 
 TextMode="MultiLine" ontextchanged="txtOtherApps_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
```

How to display link in this textbox?

Comment: A link the user can click? You can't.

Comment: Do you mean a clickable link? Or just the text of the URL?

Comment: yes i meant clickable link in textbox..is it possible?

Comment: how is the text going to make it into the text box in the first place?  is the user going to enter it and then click it? or are you displaying it to the user and for some reason you need to display it in a text box?

Answer (score 1):

The `TextBox` allows you to display *text* which the user can edit. It does not allow you to display anything but plain text. To display a URL in the `TextBox`, simply set its `Text` property:

```
txtOtherApps.Text = "http://www.example.com/";
```

It wont, however, be a "link". Clicking the URL will cause a text cursor to be placed, allowing for the user to edit the URL.

Answer (score 1):

**It is possible if you use JavaScript**
Use JavaScript on your text element - such that:

```
<input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" value="http://www.google.com" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer' ;" onClick="window.open(this.value);"/>
```

Only Java script can do what you are asking for.

Comment: In what situations would this be useful?

Comment: The above java scripted input box would show a "hand" cursor when the user hovers on it and will open desired web page once clicked on it. I think xrx215's question was to have such a text box.
desirably, the textbox should be made non-editable.


Copy paste above input on to a simple HTML page and you can check out the situations how it works! 

Now if you are asking me what is its utility? I don't know, I am not sure why @xrx215 wants a textbox that needs to behave like an <a> - he could just display a label instead.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to click on the link, but you can just set the Text property of the TextBox to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET will render `TextBox`es as `textarea`s (in your case, because it's multiline) or `input`s. These are standard HTML fragments which are just plain text containers. You can style them, but you can't really linkify the contents of them.

If you really just want to put the text of a link into a box, do this:

```
// either from the server:
txtOtherApps.Text = YourLinkString;

// or from the client:
<script>
  document.getElementById('<%=txtOtherApps.ClientID%>').value = YourJsLinkValue;
</script>
```

If you want something to happen with the user clicks on the text area, you can add an onclick handler to it...but this would be weird.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a RichTextBox. The .NET one is not available for web applications, but there are a few third party solutions available.

http://www.richtextbox.com/ is one of them, you will have to see for yourself if there is any available that suits your needs better.